# Issue while displaying action bar with title in android 4.0 or higher

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

i am using action bar in my app.i used sherlock library to display action bar below android version 3.0.it's working fine.I want to add title bar into my app.i did the following:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title_layout);
```

And in xml i did this :

```
<style name="title_theme" parent="@style/Sherlock.__Theme.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50dip</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/title_theme</item>
    </style>
```

it worked on Android api < 3.0, but above 3.0 it doesn't work.it says:

```
You cannot combine custom titles with other title feature..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be there is no need to use title bar because action bar supports title feature 
 So you have to add just 
`getSherlockActivity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle("some text");`
have  you tried this
`getSherlockActivity.getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customNav);
getSherlockActivity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);`

Comment: see the updated answer...(sherlock not supported custom title but above two lines supported)

Comment: Thanks, but whatever i have put the code in my question,though that it is supporting custom title but only in pre-3.0 not post 3.0.

Comment: i am using SherlockFragmentActivity and getSherlockActivity() is not available.

Comment: if your class extends with `SherlockFragment` then you can use getSherlockActivity()